# Measuring Frequency Synthesizer specifications

Tags: measurement, synthesizer, frequency-synthesis

I need to measure all the electrical specifications of the Frequency Synthesizer KSN-2346A+ from Mini Circuits that appears in this datasheet: https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/KSN-2346A+.pdf

but the problem is that there's no information about how can I start. For example, in that datasheet an Evaluation Board ([TB-567+](https://www.minicircuits.com/pcb/WTB-567+_P02.pdf)) is mentioned, but I don't know if I have to use it or not, or why would prefer using it or not. And there's no Application Note or nothing. The evaluation board "datasheet" is just the circuit that it uses, but nothing is specified.

So I would like to know where can I get more information, or if any of you used this circuit or measured something similar or anything. I'm reading about others Frequency Synthesizer but I need to measure the specific characteristics of this one.

This is what I understand from the TB-567+ datasheet:

- in CON4 I have to put a signal generator with an output impedance of 50 ohms and a frequency of 15 MHz.
- in CON2 I have to put a DC signal of 10V

So,

- what do I have to connect in CON1?
- I suppose that CON5 can be measured with a Spectrum Analyzer. Is that OK? Or is there any other instrument that is better?
- what do I have to connect in CON3?

Thanks

Comment: is this a school assignment?  .... why do you need to measure the electrical characteristics?

Comment: No, this is just a small part of a project for university. I have to do much more things, but now I was asked to measure those characteristics. Can you please help me?

Comment: Or at least I would like more information about the KSN-2346A+ and the evaluation board TB-567. Application Notes of something

Answer (score 1):

The TB-567 appears to be a generic test board you can use to evaluate several models  (maybe families) of Minicircuits devices.

You get a TB-567 and mount your synthesizer on it.

You use the TB-567 rather than building your own so that you don't have to design and have a PCB made and assembled.

You can't plop a 2GHz device on a breadboard and expect to do anything useful, so Minicircuits provides the TB-567 to help you get going.

You **could** design a PCB with power and RF connectors and have it made and assembled.  If you go that way, though, part of your test will be verifying that your own design is correct and correctly carried out.

---

Yes, Con4 is the 15MHz in and Con5 is the synthesized output.

Looks like you also have to provide data to program the synthesizer output.  The TB-567  provides a USB connector and associated hardware.  You'll probably have to have a program on your PC to tell the synthesizer what to do.

Really, you need to contact Minicircuits for more information.  There's more to this than you might imagine at first glance.

For example, the datasheet doesn't mention how to use data and clock to program the synthesizer.  Maybe it has default settings - but the datasheet doesn't mention that, either.

Comment: Nice. But today is saturday and mini-circuits people work from monday to friday and I need to solve this between today and tomorrow. What can I do? Is there any other similar frequency synthesizer that has an application note or something? Anyway, I need to measure the specifications of the KSN-2346A+ but it would be useful, I suppose

Comment: Errrm. Even if the minicircuits people answer, you won't be getting hold of a TB-567 before Monday.  If your deadline for the measurement is Monday, then I'd say you are screwed.  If the deadline was short (assigned Wednesday and due Monday) then maybe your professor will accept a plan for measurement if you explain the problems.  If you had a couple of months, and only now started looking then you are in trouble.